# C fwrite error: mcleanup

Tags: c, codeblocks, fwrite

Codeblocks, C. I'm trying to write characters to a .txt file, using fwrite. The first couple of characters get written correctly, but after them the file says: _mcleanup: tos ov. I think it might be a buffer overload. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    FILE*p1;

    p1=fopen("Tomi.txt","w+");

    fseek(p1,0,SEEK_SET);

   // fwrite("Toth Tamas",sizeof(char),30,p1);

    while(a<10)
        {
            fwrite("Toth Tamas",sizeof("Toth Tamas"),1,p1);

            a++;

        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've put the code in the discription. I tried it with while, and with only fwrite as well.

Comment: This probably isn't your immediate problem, but you should always call `fwrite` (and `fread`) with the *second* argument 1 and the *third* argument equal to the amount of data you want to write (or read).  Otherwise it is impossible to recover from short writes (or reads).  Note also that `sizeof(char)==1` *by definition*, and therefore `sizeof(char)` is a bad code smell.

Comment: Thank You! But its still not okay. I've added int a=0; right after FILE*p1. The characters've been written in the file, as you can read:Toth Tamas  _mcleanup: tos oveToth Tamas Toth Tamas Toth Tamas Toth Tamas Toth Tamas Toth Tamas Toth Tamas Toth Tamas Toth Tamas Toth Tamas

Comment: This behavior would be expected (assuming the hypothesis in my answer is correct) for a version of the program that had *both* the while loop and the standalone `fwrite` uncommented.  I only tested it as shown, with the standalone `fwrite` commented out.

Answer (score 0):

If I add `int a = 0;` immediately after `FILE *p1;`, the while-loop version of the program compiles without complaint, even with maximum warnings, and executes without error on my computer, even under valgrind.  You want `sizeof("Toth Tamas") - 1` in the `fwrite` call to prevent NUL bytes from being written to the file, and maybe there should be an `\n` after "Tamas", and see my earlier comments for other minor problems, but that code seems mostly okay.

However, the commented-out line `//fwrite("Toth Tamas",sizeof(char),30,p1);` does have a bug: the string constant `"Toth Tamas"` is only 11 bytes long (counting the terminating NUL), but you have asked `fwrite` to write 30 bytes, so it will access 19 more bytes beyond the end of the string, triggering undefined behavior.  In context, one would expect either a segmentation fault, or garbage written to the file.

And "_mcleanup: tos ov" is 17 bytes long, so if that is (the beginning of) the next string constant in the read-only data segment of your executable, it's a plausible thing to show up as garbage written to the file, which I *think* is what you are saying happened.